# How to use the distinct on databases DB4O

Tags: database, distinct, db4o, group-by

the data like this:
file1    file2
aaaa      milk
aaaa      red
bbbb      box
bbbb      pen
cccc      rose
i want get result like this:
file1:
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
who can tell me how to do using DB4objects
waiting online....

Comment: Can you provide more information? In which environment, Java or .NET? Distinct on a field or an object?

Comment: like this : people has two properties , one is sex the other one is name , i want distinct sex .the result is 'man' or 'women'.using .net in db4o thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know db4o has no direct support for the 'distinct' operation. However since you're using the .NET-framework you can use the LINQ-Distinct operation on you result. I assume you're using .NET 3.5 and C#. Tell me when I'm wrong.

For example:

```
  IObjectContainer db = // ...
  var persons = (from Person p in db
       select p).Distinct();
```

This will return the distinct result of all Person-objects. It will use the GetHashCode() and Equals()-Methods to compare the objects.

When you don't want to use a the default equal comparison, you can pass an IEqualityOperator-instance to the distinct method:

```
    class PersonByNameEquality : IEqualityComparer<Person>
    {
        public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
        {
            return x.Firstname.Equals(y.Firstname);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
        {
            return obj.Firstname.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    // and then
    IObjectContainer db = //...
    var persons = (from Person p in db
                   select p).Distinct(new PersonByNameEquality());
```